# Run Delayed Job at heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I am trying to run DelayedJob at Heroku but for some reason Jobs are not running I have followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) tutorial for setting the delayed job. It is working fine locally, and works fine at production and when I run `heroku run rake jobs:work` from terminal. But I want to run it in background it should not stick to my terminal.

I have "`worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work`" in my procfile but still its not working

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Did you scale your worker dynos to at least 1?

Comment: yes i have done that 

heroku ps --app abc
=== web (1X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: up 2014/06/16 21:09:09 (~ 25m ago)

=== worker (1X): `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
worker.1: up 2014/06/16 21:09:03 (~ 25m ago)